# UIImageView strange crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

Here is code:

```
-(void)initView
{
        increaseImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(277, 189, 511, 406)]autorelease];
         ..
         ..
         increaseImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgarray lastObject]];
         ..
         ..
}


-(void)cleanUpView
{

    if(increaseImage)
    {
        if([increaseImage superview]!=nil )
            [increaseImage removeFromSuperview];    //Crashes Here

        increaseImage = nil;
    }
}
```

Crashes in removeFromSuperview line..How to avoid crash?

**NOTES:**
    Not using ARC
    I wish to fix problem with autorelease only..why crash...it worked for other object. Lots of view is used so Its difficult to change autorelease. So wish to find right reason..

Comment: A crash log and stacktrace  would be nice.

Comment: do not use autorelease

Comment: not using ARC, why not autorelease? autorelease worked for other onjects..

Comment: When you use `autorelease`, can't you just remove that code from `cleanUpView`? Or do you have memory leaks then?

Comment: yes memory leak also there...when I remove autorelease then no crash, not getting why autorelease making crash here

Answer (score 2):

remove `autorelease` at alloc time of `increaseImage` like bellow..

replace this line

```
increaseImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(277, 189, 511, 406)]autorelease];
```

with bellow line

```
increaseImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(277, 189, 511, 406)];
```

Comment: I think using ARC will defend code in situations like this.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin some time when object is not live in the class and we try to remove it at that time this bad_access occur .. :)

Comment: not using ARC, autorelease worked for other object..I wish to fix with autorelease...like to find right reason.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try like this:

```
-(void)initView
 {
        increaseImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(277, 189, 511, 406)];
         ..
         ..
        increaseImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgarray lastObject]];
         ..
         ..
 }


-(void)cleanUpView
 {

   if(increaseImage)
   {
      if([increaseImage superview]!=nil )
        [increaseImage removeFromSuperview];    
        [increaseImage release];  // release here instead of autorelease
        increaseImage = nil;
   }
 }
```

Comment: not using ARC, autorelease worked for other object..I wish to fix with autorelease...like to find right reason....